# What is a trigger function

Tags: vb6

What is a trigger function with respect to event driven programming? And especially with regard to vb6.

I have searched microsoft documentation as thoroughly as I can and come up with a blank.

Comment: Good question.  In what context did you here the name "trigger function" mentioned?

Comment: A BTEC course question. The question is asking to explain the main features of event driven programming languages. Specifically with regards to a) it being service orientated, b) time driven, and with regard to c) event triggers and handlers

Comment: They are probably just using the word "trigger" in a generic sense.  "Raise" or "cause" might be other words used to describe the same thing.  "Trigger function" seems like a completely vacuous phrase though, and "triggering operation" feels more meaningful to me.  As in "VB6's RaiseEvent statement performs a triggering operation on event listeners."

Answer (score 1):

Triggers are common in DB environment (SQL Server, etc). As far as I know, there are no triggers in VB6 per se.

You can apply a trigger on a table to perform a certain task when data in that table changes (a new record inserted, etc).

[More info on SQL Server triggers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178110.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm aware of DB triggers and I thought there might be a link. I'm at a loss as far as event driven programming though...my google skills are failing me. And it must be an established term because it is in the BTEC spec

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as a "trigger function" in VB6.  I think you have misunderstood the wording a bit.

An Event is the concept of something that happens in the application, like a button click, mouse move, form load, etc.

Each Event may be handled by an Event Handler, which is a function that is executed when a given event occurs on a given object, e.g. Button1_Click for handling the Click event on a button named Button1.  Note:  This function is called Handler function, not Trigger function.

An Event may be Triggered (more often called Raised), which means that an object indicates to the environment that the event has occurred.  In the above example, the button named Button1 Triggers/Raises the Click Event.